# Como fazer 2 insert ao mesmo tempo com PHP no Banco de Dados MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, view

Banco de Dados:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb;

USE mydb;

CREATE TABLE clientes (
  cod_clientes INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_clientes)
) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE erros(
  cod_erros INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome_erro VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
  solucao VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  data_ocorrencia DATE,
  sistema VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_erros)
  ) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE funcionarios (
  cod_funcionarios INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  login VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  senha VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  cpf VARCHAR (11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (cod_funcionarios),
  Fk_Clientes INT UNSIGNED,
  Fk_Erros INT UNSIGNED,
  FOREIGN KEY Fk_Clientes (Fk_Clientes) REFERENCES clientes (cod_clientes) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY Fk_Erros (Fk_erros) REFERENCES erros (cod_erros) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
  ) ENGINE = innodb;
```

View:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_LISTA_ERROS AS SELECT nome AS Cliente, 
nome_erro AS Erro, solucao AS Solucao, 
data_ocorrencia AS Data, sistema AS Sistema 
FROM  erros, clientes;

select *from VIEW_LISTA_ERROS;
```

Parte do código do PHP onde estou tentando o Insert:

```
if ($row == 0) {
    $query = "insert into erros(nome_erro,solucao,data_ocorrencia,sistema)
    values('{$nome_erro}', ('{$solucao}'), ('{$data}'), '{$sistema}')";

    $query2 = "insert into clientes(nome)
    values('{$nome_cliente}'";

    mysqli_query(conexao(), $query);

    mysqli_query(conexao(), $query2);

    header('location: paginaConsulta.php');
  }
}
```

Comment: a resposta te ajudou? Se sim, procure marcá-la para ajudar outros colegas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, mude a ordem da execução assim:

```
if ($row == 0) {
    $query = "insert into erros(nome_erro,solucao,data_ocorrencia,sistema)
    values('{$nome_erro}', ('{$solucao}'), ('{$data}'), '{$sistema}')";
    mysqli_query(conexao(), $query);

    $query2 = "insert into clientes(nome)
    values('{$nome_cliente}'";
    mysqli_query(conexao(), $query2);

    header('location: paginaConsulta.php');
  }
}
```

veja se vai te ajudar

Comment: Ele não está inserindo na tabela "clientes". E quando eu puxo a view, ele traz todos os outros dados que eu cadastrei, menos o cliente novo cadastrado. Ou seja, só está cadastrando os dados da tabela erros. Acredito que eu teria que fazer uma prociedure para isso, mas n sei como faz no php, etc.